# Is it possible to save the result of a generator passage with map() in Python?

Tags: python

```
x = (i for i in range(10))

result = []
for i in x:
    result.append(i)
```

Is it possible to do the same with map() instead of for()?

Comment: You don't need `map` for this. You can just use `result = list(x)`.

Comment: You may try list(x)

Comment: haha, thanks!)) So simple

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = [i for i in range(10)]
```